# How to configure bearer-only = true when Using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth, keycloak, api-gateway

I am trying to setup o auth2 authentication in spring cloud gateway for my rest apis using keycloak. keyclcoak redirects my request to login page while passing access token as bearer token. In many places I found solution for this is to set bearer-only = true in keycloak adapter. where to set this while using spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client. I cannot use keycloak-spring-boot-starter to set this in application.yml

Thanks

Comment: What makes you want to use spring-security-oauth2-client? The client module is for obtaining a token through an OAuth 2.0 grant flow. How does the gateway you are building know what the token is? If it's simply given to the gateway in the `Authorization` header, then spring-security-oauth2-resource-server is what does that.

Comment: @jzheaux I am trying to do authentication in the gateway for my services running behind it. I set up an keycloack server with realm, users and  roles, with my token end point I can get the oauth2 token. I want to pass this token with the request and get authenticated in gateway. I am new to this spring framework.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. How are you passing the token to the gateway? Does the caller hand it to the gateway in an `Authorization` header, for example?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question as you. Not having found an answer, I developed a filter with a light keycloak Client that calls the Endpoint instrospect of keycloak to validate the token

the client:

```
public class KeycloakClient {

private final KeycloakConfigurationProperties kcProperties;
private final WebClient client;

public KeycloakClient(final KeycloakConfigurationProperties keycloakConfigurationProperties) {
    this.kcProperties = keycloakConfigurationProperties;
    this.client = WebClient.builder()
                           .baseUrl(keycloakConfigurationProperties.getAuth_server_url())
                           .filter(logRequest())
                           .build();
}

public Mono<Boolean> validateBearerToken(String bearerToken) {
    //todo: improve error management
    return prepareAndRunRequest(bearerToken).retrieve()
                                            .bodyToMono(KeycloakValidationResponse.class)
                                            .flatMap(response -> Mono.just(response.getActive()))
                                            .onErrorResume(WebClientResponseException.class,
                                                           ex -> Mono.just(false));
}

private WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> prepareAndRunRequest(String bearerToken) {

    return client.post()
                 .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/auth/realms/")
                                              .path(kcProperties.getRealm())
                                              .path("/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect")
                                              .build())
                 .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                 .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData("client_id", kcProperties.getResource())
                                    .with("client_secret", kcProperties.getCredentials_secret())
```

the filter:

```
public class ValidationTokenGatewayFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<ValidationTokenGatewayFilterFactory.Config> {

private final KeycloakClient client;

public ValidationTokenGatewayFilterFactory(KeycloakClient client) {
    super(Config.class);
    this.client = client;
}

@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
    return (exchange, chain) -> {

        String token = exchange.getRequest()
                               .getHeaders()
                               .get(AUTHORIZATION)
                               .get(0);

        token = token.substring(7);

        log.trace("-- ValidationToken(): token={}", token);

        return client.validateBearerToken(token)
                     .flatMap(validated -> {
                         if (validated) {
                             log.debug("-- ValidationToken(): Token valid");
                             return chain.filter(exchange);
                         } else {
                             log.debug("-- ValidationToken(): Token invalid");
                             exchange.getResponse()
                                     .setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);

                             return exchange.getResponse()
                                            .setComplete();
                         }
                     });
    };
}

public static class Config {
}
```

}

You can find a full sample here: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2105967